# Multiple Conditions in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I'm trying to redirect images on my server to a url, if the user client is NOT A BOT.
So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Windows" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} jpg
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But something is wrong. Is it possible to combine these 2 conditions?

Comment: What tells you that something is wrong? It is helpful to give examples of what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: What's wrong?  The conditions should fall through if true.  What values are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Successive RewriteCond should be ANDed together if there's not an explicit OR flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Does this not appear to be happening?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect so that humans can't see images. (ex: myurl.com/image.jpg to redirect to myurl.com/)

Comment: Pretty much I'm trying to bypass the new google images previews. Whenever a user clicks "Full Size Image" and see the image at the source, it would redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is admirable, but the logic is flawed based on real world bot behavior.

I deal with security on sites all the time & User Agent strings are faked all the time. If have an option to install it, I would recommend using a tool like [Mod Security](http://www.modsecurity.org). It’s basically an Apache module firewall that uses configurable rulesets to deny bad patterns of access behavior. But honestly, if you are having issues with `.htaccess` stuff like this Mod Security might be too intense to understand.

A better tact is to just prevent hot-linking via [mod_rewrite tricks like this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess10.shtml).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.mydomain.com/angryman.gif [R,L]
```

Then again, reading your question I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve? Maybe `mod_rewrite` stuff like this can give you hints on how to approach the issue? Good luck!

Comment: I don't really care about faking user agents, because majority wont.
Pretty much I'm trying to bypass the new google images previews. Whenever a user clicks "Full Size Image" and see the image at the source, it would redirect.